# How to ensure to show exit ad in android?

Tags: android, interstitial, mopub

In my android app I'm using [MoPub](http://www.mopub.com/) to show an interstitial on app exit. It is working fine, except when user quickly presses back button twice, app exits without showing any interstitial. I want to ensure that interstitial is shown if it's available.

Here's the relevant code

```
// InterstitialAdListener methods
    @Override
    public void onInterstitialLoaded(MoPubInterstitial interstitial) {
        // This sample automatically shows the ad as soon as it's loaded, but
        // you can move this show call to a time more appropriate for your app.
        // if (interstitial.isReady()) {
        //    mMoPubInterstitial.show();
        // }
        // We're doing nothing here, we'll load the ad when exit
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterstitialFailed(MoPubInterstitial interstitial, MoPubErrorCode errorCode) {
        Log.d("MoPub", "Interstitial load failed: " + errorCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterstitialShown(MoPubInterstitial interstitial) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterstitialClicked(MoPubInterstitial interstitial) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterstitialDismissed(MoPubInterstitial interstitial) {
        finish(); //this will exit the program if interstitial is closed
    }
```

And here's my onBackPressed method where I'm showing the ad

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
            if (mInterstitial.isReady()) {
                mInterstitial.show(); //this will show the interstitial if it's ready
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed(); //this will exit the program
            }
    }
```

Comment: If you are planning to distribute your app through Google Play then you should not show ad on exit as its a Google Play ad policy violation!

Comment: @MuhammadBabar It's not shown after the app is closed, it's shown when user presses back button on main activity and when user dismisses the ad, app is closed. I think it's better user experience. Can you provide document where it's said that doing such is against google's policies.

Comment: Here you go https://play.google.com/about/monetization.html#ads-policy read `Interfering with Apps, Third-party Ads, or Device Functionality`

Comment: @MuhammadBabar I've read and seen the examples and none of those include the way I'm doing it. Should I add a dialog for exiting the app too. Technically the activity and app is not closed and ad is cached and can be considered as part of the app and Is shown before exiting the app and not after and doesn't cover the system UI. It seems risky but technically it should be correct. What does google want, should we not earn anything?

Comment: Did you read this line `Ads that are triggered by the home button or other features explicitly designed for exiting the app:` back button is also used to exit/close the app so you might get into trouble!

Comment: @MuhammadBabar I've disabled ads from mopub admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement/override  onBackButtonPreesed  method. Where u can use a counter which tracks how many times user clicks it. Therefore, no matter how many times or quickly user presses it, you can have full control over it. So you, on click of back button check net connection and show ads and finish your activity.

Comment: I've added my onBackPressed method in my question.